# call a string/function from database

Tags: php, functions, themes

I need call a string from `$_POST["m_giambellino"]`, etc... (see down), saved in database of wordpress:

```
if ($_POST["send"] == "Save")

    {

        update_option("mese_giambellino", $_POST["m_giambellino"]);
        update_option("giorno_giambellino", $_POST["g_giambellino"]);
        update_option("mese_teramo", $_POST["m_teramo"]);
        update_option("giorno_teramo", $_POST["g_teramo"]);
        update_option("mese_solari", $_POST["m_solari"]);
        update_option("giorno_solari", $_POST["g_solari"]);

        echo "Evento/i salvati con successo!";

    }
```

into a theme (for example: `<div><?php get_$_POST["m_giambellino"] ?></div>`).

How can I do it?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe like this

```
get_option( "mese_giambellino" );
```

This retrieves what you saved with `update_option()`

More about [WP options](http://codex.wordpress.org/Options_API) you can read [here (http://codex.wordpress.org/Options_API)](http://codex.wordpress.org/Options_API)

Comment: I've an another question: i'm looking a valua simliar ":contains" but that i can find a specific number and not the specific number in a variable digits number... (for example: contains('2')...it will look number that contain number 2 (so, 2, 22, 24, 25...) and it make error...can you help me?

Comment: @user12932 where do you search this number?